# How can I get an array of strings from an excel column?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to import an excel file and create arrays for each column in the excel file. In column A there are strings and in columns B & C there are numbers. I have been able to import columns B & C as arrays, but am left with an empty array where I want an array of strings.

I have tried using `[~, text]=xlsread('myfile.xlsx', 'A:A');`, but the array is still empty.

I want to create this array of strings to be able to print the strings to a text file in this sort of fashion `fprintf(fileID, 'Some words here %s other words here', text(i));` where the `%s` will be replaced by the string from the array text at index `i`.

Comment: `readtable( 'myfile.xlsx' );` is more intelligent than `xlsread( 'myfile.xlsx' )`, and will handle different variable types nicely. Look in the docs for optional inputs.

Comment: @Woflie I've used readtable() and was able to get all the data from my excel spreadsheet into a table. But I'm not familiar with readtable(), how would I go about using the table I created to print out the specific strings in fprintf statement I've described above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why what you've posted doesn't work - can you show an example of the spreadsheet?

However the `text` and `raw` outputs from `[num, text, raw] = xlsread(myfile.xls)` (in MATLAB R2018b, so it should be the same in any earlier version) are cell arrays, not string arrays. To index an individual string (or technically, character vector) you need to use curly brackets, e.g.:

```
fprintf(fileID, 'Some words here %s other words here', text{i});
```

Be aware that `xlsread` will strip off blank or non-numeric rows and columns before and after the data it returns in `num`, and blank or non-text rows and columns before and after what it returns in `text`, so if your data has headers or blank rows before the numeric data then the row indices of your numeric array might not match the row indices of the cell array containing the text cells.

As Wolfie suggests, an alternative is to use `readtable` instead of `xlsread`. It's up to you to decide whether using the table datatype would make more sense in the rest of your program.